# Improve your HTML editor

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Whoever developed this, it is a very good website, but I know you can do better with the HTML editor. Pasting code here is so difficult. I have developed better websites with HTML editor controls for free, out there.

Comment: Pasting code is trivial. 1. Press your browser's Paste key combo 2. Select the code. 3. Click the code button.

Comment: *"I have developed better websites with HTML editor controls for free, out there."* I'll believe it when I see it.

Comment: www.aureliumclub.be, www.luon.be, www.epm.com.co, 15 years of experience will make me think that I am right when I see a good and a better editor, this is not bad, but its not good for the users, and as a user, the site should take that into account, customers are always right

Comment: @Quentin - one only has to follow stackoverflow.com for a short while to see how many questions have very poorly formatted code.  If it was so easy to have properly formatted code on stackoverflow.com, then why are there so many poorly formatted posts?  Might it have something to do with how bad the editor is for pasting code and how undiscoverable some of its feature are?  Yeah, probably.  The editing capabilities for a site primarily about code are pretty atrocious and remind me of things I dealt with in the 1980s.  It could be a lot better than it is.

Comment: I don't understand how to make better website using html editor. Please give me a link so that I can believe you.

Answer (score 10):

**The first problem is that it's not really an HTML editor.** It intentionally supports only a [limited subset](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) of HTML markup, and because most people don't write HTML at all, there's no specialized functionality to help you write HTML (like auto-complete, auto-close, etc.)

If you want to be a real pro at posting questions/answers on Stack Overflow, you should take some time to familiarize yourself with the [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) syntax that we do support. There's a help page located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (the same one that is linked from the "help" icon at the top of the edit window) that introduces it all to you. The big benefit of Markdown over HTML is that the Markdown syntax is quite intuitive and attempts to mirror the way people would write in plain ASCII format when no rich formatting at all was available.

For example, bold is indicated with two asterisks surrounding the word or phrase, `**like this**`.

And to make common tasks even simpler, you can use the icons on the toolbar at the top of the editing window. That gives you one-click access to almost all of the markdown you'll be using on a regular basis, including the ability to upload images and create hyperlinks.

Comment: exact, when no rich formatting at all was available, but rich formatting has been available for many years, why use and old fashioned way instead of a modern way that everyone knows in all codes. go to msdn forums and see how you can insert code.  I am not saying that its not easy to do here, but definitely its more intuitive rich editors.

Comment: @Luis: There is absolutely nothing "modern" about HTML. Markdown is a *far* more modern syntax, and much more easily understandable to the average person. Remember that Stack Overflow is part of the larger Stack Exchange network, which offers a whole host of Q&A sites not just targeted to programmers. Normal people often don't know HTML. And in fact, lots of programmers don't know HTML either. If you write embedded C++ applications, you might have never learned HTML at all. Markdown is intuitive to pick up, even after a brief tutorial.

Comment: I've used the MSDN forums, and there's nothing spectacular about that editor by comparison. We also offer a live preview underneath the post, just like MSDN does to the right. Syntax highlighting is automatically applied based on the tags you specify for the question, or can be manually overridden as described in the above-linked documentation. I really don't see where anything can be improved.